# Access token doesn't contain any scopes

Tags: facebook-graph-api, scope, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

I want to get a list of my friends with their name, current location and profile picture. I executed the query and the access token (with the required scope parameters) in the GRAPH API explorer tool and it works fine --> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%3Ffields%3Dname%2Clocation%2Cpicture

But everytime I execute the application, I get an access token without the required scope (it has none). How can I send my scopes to the access token?

Scope I want to give to the access token: Scopes: friends_location user_location user_relationships

I work in a localhost environment.

```
 <html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js"></script>

<script> 
var accessToken
var uid

 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '493774134048550', // App ID
    channelUrl : '//localhost/Facebook', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
  // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
  // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below 
  // will be handled. 
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
      // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
      // have logged in to the app.

    uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    console.log(uid);
    console.log(accessToken);

    testAPI(function(response) {
           // handle the response
           uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    console.log(uid);
    console.log(accessToken);
         }, {scope: 'friends_location, user_location, user_relationships'});

    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
      // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
      // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
      // like this, for two reasons:
      // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
      // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
      // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.

      //FB.login();
      FB.login(function(response) {
           // handle the response
           uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    console.log(uid);
    console.log(accessToken);
         }, {scope: 'friends_location, user_location, user_relationships'});

    } else {
      // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
      // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
      // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
      // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
      // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.

//   FB.login();

          FB.login(function(response) {
           // handle the response
           uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;µ
    console.log(uid);
    console.log(accessToken);
         }, {scope: 'friends_location, user_location, user_relationships'});
    }
  }, {scope: 'friends_location, user_location, user_relationships'});




  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
  // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    //FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    //  console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    //  console.log(response);
    //});

    ///me/friends?fields=name,location,picture&accesstoken=CAACEdEose0cBAFhNXAYgMjfAPWNxGZAdNdEJ6s2GAyIQp4zicpV0ZBZCeVINbiLvIxaFl33N0I1gZAZArREsHmOGiqQX2HPaNZCiU4W4Nq3VA12TrreKfeOtFSMvmZC8c1qYqu85NZAzzWDXWH5foXIWfPFk1ZBScNbAZD
    FB.api('/'+uid+'/friends?fields=name,location,picture&accesstoken='+accessToken, function(response) {

    //FB.api('/'+uid+'/friends?fields=name,location,picture&accesstoken=CAACEdEose0cBAJayThSg77Ydil76EM0W4zuJ9l29yKoIxlu6g37ZAX1CWQhpTStBL48xoX5g0Bbe8Va4wr6qqT2ft5tZBoNDZCWFYF7TtwmBnTDOSGWruOp0pSS9Ws1phfl5wiFbHeZAyUbdZBDdx3GLBHeysn6EZD', function(response) {
      var teller1 = 0;
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
      console.log(response.data);
     for (var i=0;i<response.data.length;i++)
    { 

    if(response.data[i].name && response.data[i].location && response.data[i].picture){
    console.log(response.data[i].name);
      console.log(response.data[i].location.name);
      console.log(response.data[i].picture.data.url);
    teller1++;
    }


      //<img border="0" src="console.log(response.data[0].picture.data.url)">
      }
      console.log(teller1); //aantal gebruikers met naam, locatie en picture
      console.log(response.data.length); //aantal gebruikers in totaal
    });


  }

  //Logout
  function fbLogout() {
        FB.init();
        FB.logout(function (response) {
            //Do what ever you want here when logged out like reloading the page
            window.location.reload();
        });
    }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses the JavaScript SDK to
  present a graphical Login button that triggers the FB.login() function when clicked.

  Learn more about options for the login button plugin:
  /docs/reference/plugins/login/ -->

<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
<span id="fbLogout" onclick="fbLogout()"><a class="fb_button fb_button_medium"><span class="fb_button_text">Logout</span></a></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at your token via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token/? What does this say?

Comment: It was empty. But now I have a correct access token. The problem was that I didn't ask for a FB.login with scope @ the right place. I had to ask it when I was connected, because otherwise, the access token (with correct scopes) after the first login was replaced by by an access token without any scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the code under response.status === 'connected' with this. Remove all other parts in the original code where the scope was added. (you only have to add it here)

```
 if (response.status === 'connected') {
          // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
          // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
          // have logged in to the app.

          if(accessToken)
          {
         // alert("Connected WITH accesToken");
          testAPI();
          }
          else{
         // alert("Connected WITHOUT accesToken");
         FB.login(function(response) {
               // handle the response
               uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        console.log(uid);
        console.log(accessToken);
             }, {scope: 'friends_location, user_location, user_relationships'});

        }
```

Comment: Never use FB.login directly in an async callback, it will be blocked immediately by the popupblocker.